Unable to add WAR-File from CURL to Wildfly Docker image
My goal was to build the WAR of my Spring Boot Application via CI, push the artifact, and retrieve that artifact in a Dockerfile to deploy it using a Wildfly Application Server docker image.
I assume that I can successfully download my artifact, but I can't work with it.
If I try to add my desired *.war to the needed location, I'm getting the following error message:
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref 6ca667ce-973a-43e8-ace1-7726e3ff5494::5prlk6x1gkvbg6ouee6nwxq24: "/artifacts.zip/build/libs/ccbackend.war": not found 
This is the Dockerfile I wrote to deploy the artifact.
FROM quay.io/wildfly/wildfly
ARG STANDALONE=standalone.xml
COPY ${STANDALONE} /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration/
WORKDIR /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/
RUN curl -L -o artifacts.zip https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/MYPROJECTID/jobs/artifacts/main/download?job=build
ARG WAR_FILE=artifacts.zip/build/libs/ccbackend.war
ADD ${WAR_FILE} .

I thought I was maybe making a mistake by setting the WAR_FILE to artifacts.zip, so I tried replacing it with:
artifacts/build/libs/ccbackend.war
Unfortunately without success.
Lastly I thought unzipping my artifact could help me out. Therefore I tried unsuccessfully to install unzip via microdnf, which is not available in the eclipse-temurin image which Wildfly is using.
No I'm clueless what I really should do or what I maybe did wrong.

does your Jenkins pipeline clean its workspace by any chance? (cleanWs()). Cause if that is the case, the articat will indeed not be found. Other than that I would need you to clarify a bit the scope of the problem - where does the not found error happen? in Docker build step?

I'm honest, I don't know if it cleans my workspace. I tried to RUN echo ls or just RUN ls without success. This is the first time I tried to deploy an application on wildfly docker server. The error is happening at exactly in my 7 line -> ADD ${WAR_FILE} .  . I assumed that the file could not be found but in this case shouldn't the error already appear the line before in ARG WAR_FILE=artifacts.zip/build/libs/ccbackend.war ?

Dockerfile is just a number of steps that you would otherwise execute manually, there is no magic there. Therefore, when something is not working, simply execute the steps one after another manually to see if there is a problem with one of the steps. In this case execute curl -L -o artifacts.zip https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/MYPROJECTID/jobs/artifacts/main/download?job=build in terminal yourself and see if it really downloads a war or not

Yes I did this indeed. Before writing the script I tried to manually download the zip to my desktop, this worked. But what I just recognized is, when I build the image with the above mentioned expression, the step goes through pretty quick. Otherwise if I leave out the output -o artifacts.zip, the step takes more time, like it is downloading. With curl -L https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/MYPROJECTID/jobs/artifacts/main/download?job=build. I once also could see the download process in my console, but just once.

this line ARG WAR_FILE=artifacts.zip/build/libs/ccbackend.war doesn't make much sense for me. You are trying to access war file inside of zip? You need to add a step to unzip the zip, THEN grab the war file

Yes I was thinking exact the same. But I could achieve to unzip it due to that I don't have the unzip package, and also because I couldn't manage to install it via yum or microdnf.

what is the problem (error message) when running um install -y unzip?

The error message which occurs is: ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c yum install -y unzip" did not complete successfully: exit code: 127

just checked, wildfly is based on redhat so you have to use dnf - try RUN dnf -y update && dnf install -y unzip

Unfortunately this didn't work 0.294 /bin/sh: line 1: dnf: command not found. But as I mentioned in my post, the don't use dnf they use microdnf. With the expression RUN microdnf -y update && microdnf install -y unzip I get -> 0.284 error: Failed to create: /var/cache/yum/metadata.
Is there maybe a problem with the users rights?

the problem is that the default user jboss doesnt have sufficient rights.
Change Dockerfile as follows:
FROM quay.io/wildfly/wildfly
ARG STANDALONE=standalone.xml
COPY ${STANDALONE} /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration/
WORKDIR /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/
RUN curl -L -o artifacts.zip https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/MYPROJECTID/jobs/artifacts/main/download?job=build

# change the user to root
USER root 
RUN microdnf install unzip -y
# change the user back to jboss
USER jboss

RUN unzip artifacts.zip
ARG WAR_FILE=artifacts/build/libs/ccbackend.war
ADD ${WAR_FILE} .


Unfortunately this did not solved my problem. My image building process no stuck at the CACHED [5/7] RUN microdnf install unzip  process. Also the ADD process gives me an error  ERROR [7/7] ADD artifacts/build/libs/ccbackend.war .  . Can't see any error message due to the never ending install unzip process

I forgot to add -y for the confirmation message - see my updated answer

This almost worked. I still had the problem, that the file could not be found. Fortunately the docker desktop application provides an analysis tool for images. I saw after unzipping the folder name artifact was deleted and the entry folder was build. With this I could finally build the image.
Thank you @J Asgarov
